# AssertionException when trying to restore fs.chunks collection (GridFS) using mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, mongorestore

**mongorestore** fails to restore a dump containing a collection called "fs.chunks" (used by [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/#gridfs-chunks-collection)).

It looks like the chunks in this collection are too big (~32MB).

```
$ mongorestore <exportDataDestination>
...
Failed: my_db.fs.chunks: error restoring from my_dump/my_db/fs.chunks.bson:  insertion error: EOF
```

Logs:

```
015-10-15T17:05:28.766+0000 I -        [conn36] Assertion: 10334:BSONObj size: 33545165 (0x1FFDBCD) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: insert: "fs.chunks"
2015-10-15T17:05:28.772+0000 I CONTROL  [conn36] 0x127b4a2 0x121c0e4 0x1208cd8 0x1208d8c 0x9754db 0xb6cde8 0x9c88bd 0xc63aa5 0xc662c0 0x9528ad 0x1228755 0x7f95c49d4182 0x7f95c470147d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
...
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2015-10-15T17:05:28.773+0000 I NETWORK  [conn36] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 10334 BSONObj size: 33545165 (0x1FFDBCD) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: insert: "fs.chunks"
```

Do you have any idea on how to tell mongo to:

- **Option 1**: Resize chunks
- **Option 2**: Accept chunks greater than 16MB

Notes:

- Mongo version: 3.1.9
- Dump was generated using mongodump tool
- All other collections are successfully restored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it in the latest version mongodb had this error. The developers recommend the use of mongorestore from previous versions. In versions of 3.0.8, 3.2.0-rc1 bugs to be out.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-939